# Flutter / Dart Error: The argument type 'Null Function(Key)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(Object)'

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart, compiler-errors

Android Studio: Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 11 Pro Max in debug mode...

```
Compiler message:
/Users/[User]/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/reorderables-0.2.12/lib/src/widgets/reorderable_flex.dart:727:18: Error: The argument type 'Null Function(Key)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(Object)'.
 - 'Key' is from 'package:flutter/src/foundation/key.dart' ('/Users/[User]/Development/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/foundation/key.dart').
 - 'Object' is from 'dart:core'.
        onLeave: (Key leaving) {},
                 ^
/Users/[User]/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/reorderables-0.2.12/lib/src/widgets/reorderable_wrap.dart:951:18: Error: The argument type 'Null Function(int)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(Object)'.
 - 'Object' is from 'dart:core'.
        onLeave: (int leaving) {},
                 ^
/Users/[User]/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/reorderables-0.2.12/lib/src/widgets/reorderable_wrap.dart:957:18: Error: The argument type 'Null Function(int)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(Object)'.
 - 'Object' is from 'dart:core'.
        onLeave: (int leaving) {},
                 ^
/Users/[User]/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/reorderables-0.2.12/lib/src/widgets/reorderable_sliver.dart:842:18: Error: The argument type 'Null Function(int)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(Object)'.
 - 'Object' is from 'dart:core'.
        onLeave: (int leaving) {},
                 ^
Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception: Errors during snapshot creation: null
Failed to build bundle.
Error launching application on iPhone 11 Pro Max.
```

Can't get an answer to pass trough this issue, any help will be greatly appreciated ☃

Comment: try to clear cache

Comment: Thanks @Doc **clearing cache usually helps**, not this time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered by [Simon Binder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11865861/simon-binder) via dart-lang/TALK-general:

> This is an error in the `reorderables` package, which you probably depend on. A report and workaround is here: [hanshengchiu/reorderables#52](https://github.com/hanshengchiu/reorderables/issues/52)

Change in **pubspec.yaml**:

```dart
#  reorderables: ^0.2.12
  reorderables:
    git:
      url: git://github.com/hanshengchiu/reorderables.git
```